# How to add date rows for messages query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got a Messages table.

```
id | sender_id | message | date
1  | 1         | Cya     | 10/10/2020
2  | 2         | Bye     | 10/10/2020
3  | 1         | Heya    | 10/11/2020
```

I want to insert `date` rows and a `type` column based on the `date`, so it looks like this.

```
id | sender_id | message | date       | type
1  | null      | null    | 10/10/2020 | date
1  | 1         | Cya     | 10/10/2020 | message
2  | 2         | Bye     | 10/10/2020 | message
2  | null      | null    | 10/11/2020 | date
3  | 1         | Heya    | 10/11/2020 | message  
3  | null      | null    | 10/11/2020 | date
```

When ordering by `date, type`, the first and the last rows are dates. And there is a `date` row between every two messages with different dates having the later date's value.

I got no idea how to tackle this one. Please tell me if you got any ideas on how to approach this.

Comment: Tag your questioon with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is ambiguous. From where you get this data in the `type` column. is it from another table and you want to create a `join` between 2 tables ?? Please put some effort into your question so, we can understand what do you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite complicated, because you want the new rows to contain the next date but the previous max id (if it exists) and also 1 row at the end.
So you can use `UNION ALL` for 3 separate cases:

```
select id, sender_id, message, date, type 
from (
  select id, sender_id, message, date, 'message' as type, 2 sort
  from Messages
  union all
  select lag(max(id), 1, min(id)) over (order by date), null, null, date, 'date', 1
  from Messages
  group by date
  union all
  select * from (
    select id, null, null, date, 'date', 3
    from Messages
    order by date desc, id desc limit 1
  )  
)
order by date, sort, id
```

Note that this will work only if your dates are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` which is comparable and the only valid date format for SQLite.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=66cdc868aa6026da2d8e97f74a3b74f4).
Results:

```
> id | sender_id | message | date       | type   
> -: | :-------- | :------ | :--------- | :------
>  1 | null      | null    | 2020-10-10 | date   
>  1 | 1         | Cya     | 2020-10-10 | message
>  2 | 2         | Bye     | 2020-10-10 | message
>  2 | null      | null    | 2020-10-11 | date   
>  3 | 1         | Heya    | 2020-10-11 | message
>  3 | null      | null    | 2020-10-11 | date
```

Comment: Tnx, the key solution was unioning a grouped and a non grouped versions of the table. The "date" id is not important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want `union all`:

```
select id, sender_id, message, date, 'message' as type
from t
union all
select id, null, null, date, 'date'
from t
order by id;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment:

```
select id, sender_id, message, date, 'message' as type
from t
union all
select min(id), null, null, date, 'date'
from t
group by date
```

Comment: This will create one `date` row for each `message` row, but I only want one `date` row for each unique `date`

Comment: @IlyaGazman . . . That is not what your question shows.  There are three `date` rows and two have duplicate dates.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I am not explaining myself well. There is a unique date for each "date" `type`, but there could be duplicated `date`s for the "message" type.